# C# Reflection code not working;

Tags: c#, reflection

I have this very simple test because the full version doesn't work either;

```
public class dfd
{
    public string g { get; set; }
}
```

and then;

```
        Type myType = typeof(dfd);
        FieldInfo[] b = myType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public);
```

When I look at b there is no field info.

```
{System.Reflection.FieldInfo[0]}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an automatic public *property*, which defines a *private* field. If you ask for the non-public fields, you'll get the backing field of that property.

BTW, you need to ask for both `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance`, otherwise you won't retrieve that field.

Comment: Yeah I JUST realised that as you were typing I think. :)

Comment: Using PropertyInfo instead.  Seemed to make more sense.